# No mapping found error using Spring MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, spring-annotations

All:

I hope that you can help me. I am pretty good when it comes to working in an application that has already been configured and setup, but the flip side is that I am apparently not very good in setting up a new application - especially when it comes to Spring MVC. I am trying to set up a very simple application so that I can build upon it later. I get a 404 error though when I run it. Everything deploys OK and compiles OK but the log shows an error of: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringTemplate/hello.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'. Can someone please explain to me what I have done wrong? I have inserted the files web.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml, some logged entries, and my HelloController.java class.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<ctx:annotation-config />
<ctx:component-scan base-package="greenthorn.com" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

Logging entries upon successful deployment

```
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Nov 10 20:51:43 EST 2010]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17dca7b8: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,helloController,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0,urlMapping,viewResolver,indexController]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2674b0ba
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler [greenthorn.com.controller.HelloController@3bbd0836]
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello/*] onto handler [greenthorn.com.controller.HelloController@3bbd0836]
INFO: Mapped URL path [/index.htm] onto handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController@64cbad03]
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 454 ms
INFO: Loading application SpringTemplate at /SpringTemplate
INFO: SpringTemplate was successfully deployed in 4,749 milliseconds.
```

HelloController.java

```
package greenthorn.com.controller;

import login.Passwordproperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import greenthorn.com.service.HelloService;
import greenthorn.com.service.PasswordService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    private HelloService helloService;

    public HelloController() {}

    /**
     * @param helloService the helloService to set
     */
    @Autowired
    public void setHelloService(HelloService helloService) {
        this.helloService = helloService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello.htm")
    public ModelAndView onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("command") Name command) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloView");
        mv.addObject("helloMessage", helloService.sayHello(command.getValue()));
        mv.addObject("greeting", "Thanks for dropping by...");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Spring 3? I am not really familiar with Spring 3 but I guess it's not working because you did not declare the HelloController Bean in the application context.

Comment: This is indeed Spring 3 (using the 3.0.2 libraries). I did not need to declare my controller in the application context because I am using annotations and have declared <ctx:component-scan base-package="greenthorn.com"/> inside of my dispatcher-servlet.xml file. Thanks for trying to help, Jeune!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current configuration `HelloController.onSubmit()` is mapped to `/hello/hello.htm` due to `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`.

If you want to map it to `/hello.htm`, you need to replace `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` with `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` (usually this mapping is used by default, but in your case defaults are not applied because you declare handler mappings manually).

Comment: Axtavt: That did the trick! It took a little digging to figure out what package DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping comes from, but when I found it and used it, I no longer got the 404 error. Thanks so much! Can you recommend a good Spring reference that could have helped me to avoid this problem in the first place?

Comment: @Clayton: Actually, most of the modern Spring tutorials are focused on using `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` only, so they don't cover interaction with other `HandlerMapping`s.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the failure may be the parameter, "@ModelAttribute("command") Name command".
this type of parameter is usually used for post method.

Comment: Tuesday: you have uncovered an error that I have not even been able to arrive at yet because of the 404 error. So while your answer did not solve the 404, it does point out another mistake I made. Thanks for taking the time to respond!